# @objc error when migrated to Swift 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode7

I had a `Swift` class declared like this:

```
@objc class MyHelper {
 // class code
}
```

I had to do this to access such class from `Objective-C` classes, since I'm mixing languages in my project. Now that I upgraded to `Xcode 7`, I get this error:

> Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc

And such class is not known by my `Objective-C` classes anymore. I guess that then I should inherit my `Swift` class from `NSObject`, will that have any impact in the way the app was working?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Apple staff SevenTenEleven's [reply](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11867) in the Apple Developer Forum.

He mentioned that this is because of `@objc` on Swift-rooted classes never quite behaved like an NSObject-rooted class, leading to various weirdness in the generated header and at runtime.

We can still treat any Swift class instance as an AnyObject, mark methods and properties on a Swift class as @objc, and conform to Objective-C protocols; the class just isn't exposed in the generated header and doesn't default to having its members available in Objective-C.